# Dynamic background image change possible?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Hey lets say i got two links on my page and i have some sub links(show up when main link clicked). Those two links have different background image.

```
*link1
-link1underlinkone
-link1underlinktwo
*link2
-link2underlinkone
-link2underlinktwo
-link2underlinkthree
```

I can easily change background image on those two main links, but how should i pass same background style to my under-links? And underunder-links if i would have any?

edit: woops forgot to tell i want change background image of BODY not the link/links ;)

Comment: Can you please share with us what you've tried? Some HTML/CSS would also be handy since it's impossible to help without seeing what you're working with.

Comment: Just use CSS classes. Use a different class for each, containing a different background image.

Comment: Maybe css inherit will work, otherwise you probably need javascript, and preferably jQuery. Or as the above poster mentions, classes will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting both the main links in seperate div's with their sub-links. Set the background on the div (set display to none so it is invisible), and then set the background on all the links to inherit, so they take the background from their parent div.

**Edit:** Use the code I made below

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #link1wrapper {
        background-image: url(background1.jpg);
        visiblity:hidden;
    }
    #link2wrapper {
        background-image: url(background2.jpg);
        visiblity:hidden;
    }
    .linkmenu a{
        background-image: inherit;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="link1wrapper" class="linkmenu">
    *link1
        -link1underlinkone
        -link1underlinktwo
</div>

<div id="link2wrapper" class="linkmenu">
    *link2
        -link2underlinkone
        -link2underlinktwo
        -link2underlinkthree
</div>

</body>
```

**Edit:** I fixed the code. Now, it puts a background on the div's and hides the div's, then I set the links in the div's to visible and voila, all the links have inherited it's background. The things you should be aware of are not to put anything else in the div's. If you do, you have to style them to set them to visible and set their background to none.

That's all I could come up with based on the very limited information you have given me. You didn't use any code, any examples, or any references, so it's very hard to answer your question accurately.

I better get an upvote for this one =p

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it and if you set the display to none, it gets rid of the links too. I'm working on a way to fix it right now

Comment: Where did this guy go? He asked a question and then disappeared while I'm sitting here waiting for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want to make a proper menu structure here is a little demo I made.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/fPu9S/

The two key properties used are `background-image: inherit` and `visibility: hidden`.

`background-image: inherit` will make the element inherit properties from its direct parent, if no image is specified this means no properties will be inherited. Due to this we need to make the `ul` for the sublinks / menu inherit the properties from its parent too... Then we mask this image on the `ul` using `visibility: hidden` and since `visibility` default setting is `inherit` we need to make the `li`s visible again with `visibility:visible`.

So thats the explanation of what is actually going on. inheriting the styles can't be used together with the anchor tags unless you nest the sub links inside the main anchors and I don't think that is even valid or accepted code.